# collapse Bootstrap не видит target если id ="{{ jinja }}"

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap

Через цикл for создаю элементы `card` с наполнением из DB которые должны сворачиваться т.к. содержимое `{{ el.story_text }}` очень большое. В качестве `id` элемента пытаюсь указать `{{ el.data }}`, она уникальная, но даже если использую `{{ el.id }}` из db ситуация не меняется, data-bs-target не видит нужный элемент. Если заменить `{{ el.data }}` в `id` на статический `id` (например `element_id`), то collapse работает, но сразу для всех созданных card.

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    test
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>История</h1>
    {% if story %}
        {% for el in story %}
            <p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{ el.date }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ el.date }}">
                {{ el.date }}
              </button>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="{{ el.date }}">
              <div class="card card-body">
                {{ el.story_text }}
              </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>У нас нет записей!</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

P.S.: Код работал при более старой версии Bootstrap, но может я что-то упустил и теперь не замечаю((

Comment: а что из себя представляет id? пример покажите

Comment: `<div class="collapse" id="{{ el.date }">` #id этого элемента должно меняться и подтягиваться из db.
 в db он заполнен на русском. просто  `date = models.CharField('Дата', max_length=50)`
id в db естественно int, но и через него не работает.

Comment: да нет, я имею в виду как выглядит id? что это - число?

Comment: не обязательно.  например  - `id="element_id"`. в данном случае что-то типа -  `id="13 января 2017 года, Москва"`

Comment: Но в любом случае начинается с числа. [Есть мнение](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id), что id обязательно должен начинаться с латинской буквы. И если Вы обратите внимание, то во втором варианте ответа (который у Вас заработал) автор добавил перед id слово "story". В 3-м бутстрапе на эту особенность, видимо, не обращали внимания, а уже в 4-м табы, модальные окна и т.д. не работают, если id начинается с цифры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    test
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>История</h1>
    {% if story %}
        {% for el in story %}
            <p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{ el.pk }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ el.pk }}">
                {{ el.date }}
              </button>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="{{ el.pk }}">
              <div class="card card-body">
                {{ el.story_text }}
              </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>У нас нет записей!</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

или вы можете так сделать

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    test
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>История</h1>
    
        {% for el in story %}
            <p>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#story{{ el.pk }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="story{{ el.pk }}">
                {{ el.date }}
              </button>
            </p>
            <div class="collapse" id="story{{ el.pk }}">
              <div class="card card-body">
                {{ el.story_text }}
              </div>
            </div>
          {% empty %}
        <p>У нас нет записей!</p>
        {% endfor %}
  
        
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: второй вариант сработал! спасибо)) странно, я уже пребывал что-то подобное, но не работало) ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @ВладимирРодионов я рад.

Comment: @amadousow, Вы бы хоть объяснили автору вопроса, что происходит, почему его вариант перестал работать, а Ваш работает и т.д.

Comment: ну да, было бы круто))